# colorful console output by unix pipe filter

Tags: linux, unix, colors, pipe, console-output

while examining the console output and logging messages of different software it is sometimes difficult to keep the overview. It would be much easier to make the output colorful and highlight the text phrases which are currently important.

Is there a program for Linux/UNIX shell which could be used as a filter by utilizing unix pipes to make the console output colorful according to predefined patterns and colors?

p.ex.
pattern definition:

```
INFO=green
WARN=yellow
ERROR=red
\d+=lightgreen
```

to highlight the severity of the message and also numbers.

usage:

```
$ chatty_software | color_filter
11:41:21.000 [green:INFO]  runtime.busevents - SensorA state updated to [lightgreen:17]
11:41:21.004 [green:INFO]  runtime.busevents - SensorB state updated to [lightgreen:20]
```

original output:

```
11:41:21.000 INFO  runtime.busevents - SensorA state updated to 17
11:41:21.004 INFO  runtime.busevents - SensorB state updated to 20
```

Answer (score 3):

we use a sed script along these lines:

```
s/.* error .*/^[[31m&^[[0m/
t done
s/.* warning .*/^[[33m&^[[0m/
t done

:done
```

and invoke it by

```
sed -f log_color.sed
```

I guess you could do something similar?

Comment: yes, you are right. I was wondering if there is a ready and comfortable solution available.